# Expected value of estimators

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we are estimating $\tau(\theta)=\frac{p}{1-p}$ for $X_1,...,X_n$ bernoulli(p) random variables.

Now I'm asked to show that there does not exist an unbiased estimator then I get
$$E_p(h(X))=\sum h(x)p^{\sum x_i}(1-p)^{\sum x_i}$$

My question is simply should I include binomial coefficients in the sum also since the sum of the $x_i$'s follow Binomail(n,p) distribution?

Comment: @Ioannis Could you stop posting misleading indications? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Did Perhaps you can tell me what is so fudamentally wrong with my comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Ioannis Sure. See answer posted below.

Comment: @Did Right. I apologise for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{0,1\}^n$ and, for every $x=(x_i)$ in $S$, $|x|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$. For every $p$ in $(0,1)$, let $\tau(p)=\frac{p}{1-p}$. Then, as you nearly wrote,
$$
E_p[h(X)]=\sum_{x\in S}h(x)p^{|x|}(1-p)^{n-|x|}.
$$
Whatever the function $h$ is, the RHS is a polynomial with respect to $p$ (with degree at most $n$), hence the $(n+1)$th derivative with respect to $p$ of $E_p[h(X)]$ is identically zero. Assume that the function $h$ is such that $E_p[h(X)]=\tau(p)$ for every $p$ in some subinterval of $(0,1)$ with nonempty interior. Then the $(n+1)$th derivative with respect to $p$ of $\tau(p)$ must be zero on this interval, a contradiction.

This proves that some unbiased estimator of $\tau(p)$ can exist based on $X$ only when $\tau$ is a polynomial function of degree at most $n$. A little more work shows that for every polynomial function of degree at most $n$, some unbiased estimator of $\tau(p)$ based on $X$ does exist.